# Problem when using same code Jquery with different values in Switch Case PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, switch-statement

I created a Switch Case and wanted the result to display the same jquery but with the values of a variable according to the Switch result! I can not think of a way to do this, anyone have any ideas?

I wanted to use the Jquery code as soon as I got a result from Case!

Switch Case code with a variable that will be used for the jquery value:

```
switch($_GET['id']){
    case 'hello':
    case 'hi':
    case 'hola':
        $variable = "IsHello";
        break;
    case $id == $row['id']:
        $variable = "IsBye";
        break;
}
```

Jquery code that will be used in each case:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            alert(<?php $variable ?>);
 </script>
```

Comment: That's just javascript, not jquery ;)

Comment: `case $id == $row['id']` Where is `$id` set?  Where is `$row` set?

Comment: I just got the code that interested

Comment: case $id == $row['id']: ?? i think it won't work

Comment: This is working, I am using this variable id outside the switch, and it is working, I already tested it!

Comment: Read the @inquam answer

Comment: @WillJohn  If "it is working", then what exactly is the question here?  What is the current result?  What is the expected result?

Comment: @Patrick Q I could not use the same javascript code in all cases, but the problem is in one of the answers, I was not using echo and when I used it I put quotes! but I already edited :)

Comment: @WillJohn Please do not edit your question to contain the answer.  This will confuse future visitors to this question and invalidate existing comments.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll leave it as it was before so I got a negative feedback and thought I had something wrong with the question, I'm new here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, to inject the value of the php variable into your javascript code you have to [echo](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('<?php echo $variable ?>');
</script>
```

The page you have the script on must also be served in a way that php actually processes it. Most often your webserver will be configured to do this as long as your file is named **.php**.

Second, you can not have a statement as a **case** in a switch statement.
You could have a **default** case and do an **if** check in that.

```
switch($_GET['id']){
    case 'hello':
    case 'hi':
    case 'hola':
        $variable = "IsHello";
        break;
    default:
        if($id == $row['id']) {
          $variable = "IsBye";
        }
        break;
}
```

**Update:** *I was told this actually is allowed in PHP and although it's not mentioned in the [manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) a quick test in PHP7 confirms this. The manual actually specifically states*

> *"In many occasions, you may want to compare the same variable (or expression) with many different **values**, and execute a different
>   piece of code depending on which **value** it equals to. This is exactly what the switch statement is for."*

*which make it a bit unexpected to allow this (although one can argue that a piece of code that evaluates to a **value** will fit the definition). But I would advise against making this a common programming technique for yourself since most other languages will look at you with a strange look in their eye.*

Comment: "you can not have a statement as a case in a switch statement"  Are you sure?  It's definitely unusually, but I don't think it is disallowed.

Comment: In basically all languages this applies. It, for instance, makes turning a switch statement into assembly etc pretty straight forward. Allowing code to be the case you check against would make that much more complicated. I think it's the same for PHP.

Comment: The only problem was that I was putting quotation marks in the echo, and it did not work, thank you :) But I can not put this code in default, since I have to check if the id is the same as found in the database, the $ row variable checks on database!

Comment: @inquam I was being subtle, but to be more straightforward, the way OP had it _is_ allowed in PHP.  As in many other cases though, just because PHP lets you do it, doesn't mean it is a great idea.

Comment: @PatrickQ: Wow, that was not excpected. And I have been using PHP since before v4 and never would have guessed that was allowed.

I would guess that it will make optimizing the precompiled byte code harder for php if you use this though.

Still can't shake you are allowed to do this :P

Comment: @WillJohn: You should be perfectly able to to that in the default clause. In fact, it's a bit of a quirk that PHP seems to allow this and in most other languages you would actually have to do this. Of the top of my head, I actually can't think of any other language of similar structure that allows this to be done in the case value's place.

Answer (score 0):

You should add quotes around php output and escape quotes as well (and don't forget to `echo` variable):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("<?php echo addslashes($variable) ?>");
</script>
```